# MySQL Definer in Store Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How to ignore definer in MySQL as if i run store procedure in MySQL without definer it took definer by default with my IP and other user unable to open it.

I just want to ignore definer in MySQL store procedure so that i will be accessed by any-other user.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure will be accessed by user if you grant EXECUTE privilege to this user, e,g -

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE db.proc1 TO 'user1'@'%';
```

Comment: i overcome above issue by following command.
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.proc TO 'mary'@'192.168.2.1'

Comment: If you need metadata, you also can view `information_schema`.`ROUTINES` system table. There is `ROUTINE_DEFINITION` field.